# iOS How to change the "Back" button's text of the Navigation Item throughout the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigation, navigationbar

Background:
I've setup my app using this [link](http://aggressive-mediocrity.blogspot.sg/2010/03/custom-localization-system-for-your.html).

This is because my app needs to change the locale on-the-fly, instead of referring to the phone's language settings.

Have a look at this [screenshot](http://bit.ly/1iUJb2s) (Pardon me, I don't have enough reputation points to upload the photo here). Right now, the language being displayed is Chinese. However, the "Back" button on the top left is in the language set in the phone's settings.

What I know now:

I am able to set the text in the "Back" by setting it in the *previous* view i.e. the view before this one is pushed.

```
UIBarButtonItem *backItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"<MY CUSTOM BACK>" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
[self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:backItem];
```

This would work, I'll be able to set the text to what I want. But this means I would need to add this code snippet in almost *every* view controllers.

My question:
I want to be able to set it in one location, and then it will apply throughout the app. I wonder if it is possible and if so, how can I achieve it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Subclass your ViewControllers from a BaseViewController which implements all your design/common methods or subclass the NavigationController and change the class in your storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

In general, I think this goes against Apple's Design Guidelines.

However, this [post](http://aggressive-mediocrity.blogspot.sg/2010/03/custom-localization-system-for-your.html) seems to provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Modify global UI customiztions in your AppDelegate's `didFinishLaounchingWithOptions` method,

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {
     [self customizeUI];
 }
```

.

```
 -(void)customizeUI
{
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                          [UIColor redColor],NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                          [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:20.0],NSFontAttributeName,
                                                          nil]
                                                forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Aspects](https://github.com/steipete/Aspects) like this:

```
[UIViewController aspect_hookSelector:@selector(viewDidLoad) withOptions:AspectPositionAfter usingBlock:^(id<AspectInfo> aspectInfo){
    UIBarButtonItem *backItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
    [((UIViewController*)aspectInfo.instance).navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:backItem];
} error:NULL];
```